# Mysql 5.6 not installing/removing/running on 15.10

Tags: server, apt, software-installation, mysql, 15.10

I have tried to purge mysql and then reinstall it 
(`sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-5.6`
), but it does not work. It looks like a dependency issue. Here is the log:

```
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.6_5.6.27-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 111, <GEN0> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value $val in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 83, <GEN7> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $val in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Format/822.pm line 84, <GEN7> line 1.
Unpacking mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.6.27-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (225-1ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.028-2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 111, <GEN0> line 7.
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Job for mysql.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (225-1ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-serverError in function: 
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.27-0ubuntu1) ...
Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in join or string at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/DbDriver/Stack.pm line 111, <GEN0> line 7.
Job for mysql.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.6; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

And then when I ran `systemctl status mysql.service` it outputted:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start-post) since Mon 2015-11-23 19:37:19 EST; 1min 3s ago
  Process: 16210 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 16207 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 16210 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS);         : 16211 (mysql-systemd-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
           ├─16211 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
           |─16781 sleep 1
```

Inputting `journalctrl -xe` spits out:

```
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 23 19:37:18 khantop systemd[1]: Reloading.
Nov 23 19:37:19 khantop systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
-- Subject: Unit cups.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit cups.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
Nov 23 19:37:19 khantop systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Nov 23 19:37:19 khantop mysqld_safe[16210]: 151123 19:37:19 mysqld_safe  Can't log to error log and syslog at the same time.  Remove all --log-e
Nov 23 19:37:19 khantop mysqld_safe[16210]: 151123 19:37:19 mysqld_safe   Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
Nov 23 19:37:19 khantop mysqld_safe[16210]: 151123 19:37:19 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Nov 23 19:37:19 khantop audit[16560]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/my.cnf" pid=16560 comm="mysq
Nov 23 19:37:19 khantop kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1448325439.865:57): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="
Nov 23 19:37:20 khantop mysqld_safe[16210]: 151123 19:37:20 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
Nov 23 19:39:01 khantop CRON[16894]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 23 19:39:01 khantop CRON[16895]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean)
Nov 23 19:39:01 khantop CRON[16894]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 23 19:41:09 khantop AptDaemon[5352]: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
Nov 23 19:41:09 khantop AptDaemon[5352]: INFO: Quitting was requested
Nov 23 19:41:09 khantop org.debian.apt[607]: 19:41:09 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting due to inactivity
Nov 23 19:41:09 khantop org.debian.apt[607]: 19:41:09 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting was requested
Nov 23 19:41:09 khantop dbus[607]: [system] Activating service name='org.debian.apt' (using servicehelper)
Nov 23 19:41:11 khantop AptDaemon[17305]: INFO: Initializing daemon
Nov 23 19:41:11 khantop org.debian.apt[607]: 19:41:11 AptDaemon [INFO]: Initializing daemon
Nov 23 19:41:11 khantop dbus[607]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.debian.apt'
Nov 23 19:41:11 khantop AptDaemon.PackageKit[17305]: INFO: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
Nov 23 19:41:11 khantop org.debian.apt[607]: 19:41:11 AptDaemon.PackageKit [INFO]: Initializing PackageKit compat layer
```

Is it because 15.10 is not officially supported by MSQL?
Thank you to anyone who takes their time to help me out!

Comment: It says: `See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` Did you?

Comment: no, I don't know how to

Comment: Those are commands. Run them. Add the output to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: AppArmor blocks the access: `apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/etc/my.cnf"`. No idea why.